# Formula with Random Number Generator

Tags: java, random

Having a bit of an issue here.  Wondering why I am getting "Infinity" for my result for my arrivalInterval method.  (tmp is defined in a previous class, I will paste both classes)  The first class, RandomNum, works just fine.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNum {

        static double x = 0.1;
        static double y = 0.2;
        static double z  = 0.3; 
        static double lamda;                                  
        static double tmp;
        static double count1, count2, count3;
        static double average;          
        static Random randomNumbGen = new Random();

        // 3 methods for testing x, y, and z
        public static double ExpInterval(double lamda)

        {
        tmp=randomNumbGen.nextDouble();            
        return (-(1/lamda) * Math.log(tmp));
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // loop that runs then methods then adds them to the count (for an an average later)     and prints out the results

for (int i=1; i<1001; i++)
count1+=ExpInterval(x);
System.out.println(ExpInterval(x));
count2+=ExpInterval(y);
System.out.println("                         " + ExpInterval(y));
count3+=ExpInterval(z);
System.out.println("                                                       " + ExpInterval(z));
}



//calculates average then prints it out
average = count1/1000;
System.out.println("The Average of the first variable is" + average +"  " + "1/lamba is " + 1/x);
average = count2/1000;
System.out.println("The average of the second variable is " + average + "   " + "1/lamba is " + 1/y);
average = count3/1000;
System.out.println("The average of the third variable is " +  average + "   " +  "1/lamba is " + 1/z);
}}
```

now for the class I am having the issue with.  If the random number picks 1, then divide .1/tmp(random number generated in first class), if 2, then .2/tmp, and if 3, then .3/tmp

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class RandomProcess extends RandomNum 
    {
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random();
    public double findArrivalInterval()
    {
    double arrivalInterval = 0.0;
    set.add(1);
    set.add(2);
    set.add(3);
    Integer result = (Integer) set.toArray()[random.nextInt(set.size())]; //only 1, 2, or 3 to be picked

    if (result == 1)
    {
    arrivalInterval = .1/tmp;
    System.out.println(arrivalInterval);
    return arrivalInterval;
    }
    if (result == 2)
    {
    arrivalInterval = .2/tmp;
    System.out.println(arrivalInterval);
    return arrivalInterval;

    }
    if (result == 3)
    {
    arrivalInterval = .3/tmp;
    System.out.println(arrivalInterval);
    return arrivalInterval;
    }
    System.out.print(arrivalInterval);
    return arrivalInterval;
    }
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
        RandomProcess testProcess = new RandomProcess();
        testProcess.findArrivalInterval();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It seems `tmp == 0`; Java floating-point division-by-zero produces either `POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `NEGATIVE_INFINITY` depending on the sign.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `tmp == 0f`; Java floating-point division-by-zero produces either `POSITIVE_INFINITY` or `NEGATIVE_INFINITY` depending on the sign.

The reason `tmp` is `0f` is because you never assign to it, so it keeps its default initialization value, which is `0f`. Note that you never call `ExpInterval`, so indeed `tmp` is never modified in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You never set `tmp` in the second class because you never call `ExpInterval`, just `findArrivalInterval`.

Also, you can write `int result = (Math.random()*3)+1` instead of all that stuff with `set`. And replace all those if statements with

```
arrivalInterval = 0.1*result/tmp
System.out.println(arrivalInterval);
return arrivalInterval;
```

Comment: But that's ok, still learning the language.  Thanks for the help with the math.random()